# How to merge two arrays by desired result with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem merging two arrays into one.

There are two arrays, which are `$count1` & `$count2`.

`$count1` gives:

[image]

`$count2` gives:

[image]

The desired result is, that there would be two arrays assigned to one variable, like `$counts`, which I could reach by indexing the first array key, like [0], and the another one by index of [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhVOV.png)].

I want to list all information to blade template but I need to combine these to arrays into one.

How could I achieve this?

`array_merge` function returns only one array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood well your question the solution is the following:

```
$counts = [
    $count1,
    $count2
];
```

By doing this, you will be able to access the values of the arrays `$count1` and `$count2` like that:

`$counts[0]['monthly']` that is the value `16`
or
`$counts[1]['all']` that is the value `61`

Answer (score 1):

You can just put both the arrays in an empty array

```
$counts = [$count1,$count2];
```

By doing this you can access `$count1` as `$count[0]` and `$count2` as `$count[1]`